# Angular retry http call only if error is the client

Tags: angular, http, rxjs, retrywhen

I'm new in angular and I would like to retry the http call if there is a network interruption or some error between client and server.
At the moment I have this configuration like suggested by official documentation

```
return this.http.get<ApiResult<Atto[]>>(this.apiEnv + "Atti")
    .pipe(
      retry(3), // retry a failed request up to 3 times
      catchError(err => this.handleError.handleError(err, {severity:'error', summary:'Impossibile recuperare gli atti', life:5000})) // then handle the error;        
    );
```

this is the error handler:

```
 public handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse, message : Message) {
    this.toastService.addSingle(message);
    return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
 };
```

I have an interceptor for the authentication or authorization error:

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(err => {
      //no authentication
      if (err.status === 401) {
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
      //no authorization
      if (err.status === 403) {
        this.auth.logout().subscribe(
          () => this.auth.logoutSuccess()
        );
      }   
      const error = err.error.message || err.statusText;
      return throwError(error);
    }))
  }
```

The problem is that all my http retry 3 times even if the problem is on the server so it is useless (futhermore the console print the handler message), I would like to retry only for communication error.
I read about `retryWhen` and `error.error instanceof ErrorEvent` to catch client-side or network error. There is a way to make all together, I can't change `retry` with `retryWhen` with the check of error instance without compiler error

Comment: `retryWhen` should do what you need. What is the problem again? You don't know how to create the chain or it's the compilation error (in that case show the error message)?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/54733093/5394220

Comment: i don't understad how can filter by isntanceof and retry 3 times. Is it possibile to make this for all http request or I have to chain all http call?